# Simple javascript bug with DOM insertion

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

I wrote this simple code to insert a word into a list, but for some reason in Chrome my changes to the DOM appear for about 1/10 of a second and then disappear. Nothing happens in Firefox.

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
window.onload = init;
function init(){
    var button = document.getElementById("submit");
    button.onclick = changeDiv;
}
function changeDiv(){
    var textInput = document.getElementById("textInput");
    var userInput = textInput.value;
    alert("adding " + userInput);
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = userInput;
    var ul = document.getElementById("ul");
    ul.appendChild(li);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form">
        <input id="textInput" type="text" placeholder="input text here">
        <input id="submit" type="submit">
    </form>
    <ul id="ul">
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not cancelling the submit button action so the page is submitting the form.

```
function changeDiv (e) {
    if (!e)
         e = window.event;

        //IE9 & Other Browsers
        if (e.stopPropagation) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
        //IE8 and Lower
        else {
          e.cancelBubble = true;
        }

    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The form is submitted and the page reloads, change

```
<input id="submit" type="submit">
```

to

```
<input id="submit" type="button">
```